# "Online" debuging on external php server

Tags: php, eclipse, git

I have big project (php+js+html), on external server. I’m wondering, is possible to work “online” on this project. On server is lot of php files with classes and functions which I would use on my computer in Eclipse (or other IDE, php debug, something more than nodepad++). I thought Git help me with this, but I don’t know, how configurate git repository, and I start wondering is this possible.

Comment: How does git helps with debugging?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You have right, i didn't described precisely what I'm looking for. Project which I mentioned, is Bitrix. I want to used bitrix function ex. (add crm product) with my parameters, and i want write this in IDE like Eclipse.    
I have to integrate bitrix and existing sytem of my company. I normaly programing in c#, delphi (desktop app) it's my firsts steps in webdeveloping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but its kill php perfomance. You can use xdebug php extension(git will not help you in this moment) You must:

- install x-debug:
  example(cent os for php71):
  `yum isntall php71-php-pecl-xdebug`
- config xdebug extension(/etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d/15-xdebug.ini):

  xdebug.remote_enable = 1
  xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
  xdebug.show_local_vars=1
  xdebug.remote_autostart=1
  xdebug.idekey = "production"
- sets idekey in your
  IDE

full documentation: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote